# How long a event (threading) can last

Tags: c++, multithreading, events

After some time after I trigger an event with SetEvent, I can still receive it with WaitForSingleObject.
I want to know,
     Will a event always be available in the OS before it's received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event object will remain in the signaled state until it is reset.  If it's an auto-reset event, then you need to be sure no other thread is going to wait on it.

As long as nobody resets the event (either implicitly or explicitly), and you don't go and delete it, you can rely on it being in the signaled state when you later call `WaitForSingleObject`.